# How to calculate the distance of two points using coordinates?

Tags: javascript, php, math, leaflet, geojson

I have a Geojson file with 100's of polylines,
eg :

```
{
  "type":"MultiLineString",
   "coordinates":
    [
     [
      [73.970889292119,15.272263607379],
      [73.970743508934,15.272184655773] 
    ]
   ]
}
```

How do I calculate the distance of the polylines in kms or how to calculate the same in leaflet?

Comment: This -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31221088/how-to-calculate-the-distance-of-a-polyline-in-leaflet-like-geojson-io -- might help

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33939754/layer-circumference-length-in-leaflet-js/33942460#33942460, but you might need to further customize it to adapt it to `MultiLineString`.

Answer (score 0):

Given an array of `polylines` you can apply a `math` formula in order to find out the **distance** from two **points** when we know the **coordonates** of the points.

[image]

```js
let polylines=[{
  "type":"MultiLineString",
   "coordinates":
    [
     [
      [73.970889292119,15.272263607379],
      [73.970743508934,15.272184655773] 
    ]
   ]
},{
  "type":"MultiLineString2",
   "coordinates":
    [
     [
      [34.970889292119,15.272263607379],
      [67.970743508934,67.272184655773] 
    ]
   ]
}];
polylines=polylines.map(function(item){
  let latitude1=item.coordinates[0][0][0];
  let longitude1=item.coordinates[0][0][1];
  let latitude2=item.coordinates[0][1][0];
  let longitude2=item.coordinates[0][1][1];
  let distance=Math.sqrt(Math.pow((latitude1-latitude2),2)+Math.pow((longitude1-longitude2),2));
  return {type:item.type, distance:distance};
});
console.log(polylines);
```

Comment: You assume plane geometry. Note that GeoJSON format is generally used for features on the Earth, i.e. on a more or less spherical geometry.